# Cumulocity CEL Check if event exists

Tags: complex-event-processing, cumulocity

I am trying to implement that if I send Event A it will create a new Event B if it does not exist. If Event B already exists it should update it instead.

I tried making a counter that counts occurences of the event but it didnt work.
Also it seems that "not exists" should be implemented but I do not get it to work.

Thanks in advance Greets

Comment: May you provide more details? Are you using Esper or Apama? Also if you post what you have done (ex: code), more people can help you!

Comment: Hey, I actually fixed the problem with creating an event if it does not exist. Right now I have the problem that I cannot access this event with UpdateEvent. When I create an event with an ID it still creates a automatic ID
insert into CreateEvent
select
    "testid" as id,
    "testtype" as type,
    part.event.source as source,
    "testext" as text,
from EventCreated as part

insert into UpdateEvent
select
    "testid" as id,
    "updatetext" as text
from EventCreated part
where
part.event.type = "testtype"

This does not work because the event is never giben the id correct

Comment: Oh and I am using Esper

Answer (score 1):

If I got it well. Your are trying to create o update an event depend if an event with the same **"key"** exist.

One approach is to create your custom "key" like so:

```
insert into 
   CreateEvent 
select 
   "testtype" as type, 
    part.event.source as source, 
    "testext" as text,
    {
     "mycustomkey" , "customValue",
     } as fragments
from EventCreated;
```

Here we create an event with a custom **key => "mycustomkey"** with a custom **value  => "customValue".**

Then when a new event is create you can use the ***"where"*** clause to know is you need to create a new event or update other event.

```
// create a new event if the firstEvent function return an event which  
// the "mycustomkey" key if different to "customValue"
insert into 
   CreateEvent 
select 
   "testtype" as type, 
    part.event.source as source, 
    "testext" as text,
    {
     "mycustomkey" , "customValue",
     } as fragments
from EventCreated e
where getString(cast(
      findFirstEventByFragmentTypeAndType("mycustomkey", "testtype"), 
      com.cumulocity.model.event), 
      "mycustomkey") != "customValue";
```

Here just update the event if the if the firstEvent function return an event which the **"mycustomkey"** if equal to **"customValue"**

```
insert into 
   EventUpdated 
select 
   "testtype" as type, 
    part.event.source as source, 
    "testext" as text,
    {
     "mycustomkey" , "customValue",
    } as fragments,
    cast(findFirstEventByFragmentTypeAndType("mycustomkey", 
    "testtype"), com.cumulocity.model.event), "mycustomkey").getId() as 
     id
from EventCreated e
where getString(cast(
      findFirstEventByFragmentTypeAndType("mycustomkey", "testtype"), 
      com.cumulocity.model.event), 
      "mycustomkey") = "customValue";
```

This solution needs that **"customValue"** must we know it and also the **findFirstEventByFragmentTypeAndType** function assumes it is going to return the event you need. We can improve this solution buy calling other function like **findOneEventByFragmentType**, **findEventByFragmentTypeAndSourceAndTimeBetweenAndType** etc..(you can find more information [here](https://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/functions/#database)) and find the event you need using a  javascript function like :

```
 insert into 
   CreateEvent 
select 
   "testtype" as type, 
    part.event.source as source, 
    "testext" as text,
    {
     "mycustomkey" , "customValue",
     } as fragments
from EventCreated e
where findTheCorrectEvent(
    findEventByFragmentTypeAndSourceAndTimeBetweenAndType(
    "mycusto mkey", "source", datefrom, dateTo).toJSON(),
    "customValue") = true;

 insert into 
   EventUpdated 
select 
   "testtype" as type, 
    part.event.source as source, 
    "testext" as text,
    {
     "mycustomkey" , "customValue",
     } as fragments
from EventCreated e
where findTheCorrectEvent(
    findEventByFragmentTypeAndSourceAndTimeBetweenAndType(
    "mycusto mkey", "source", datefrom, dateTo).toJSON(),
    "customValue") = false;

create expression Boolean findTheCorrectEvent(evens, "customValue") [ 
   var result = _findTheCorrectEvent(events, "customValue")
   function _findTheCorrectEvent(events, referenceKey){
      var _events = JSON.parse(events)
      var result = false
      _events.forEach(function(event){
          if(event.mycustomkey === referenceKey) result = true
      })
      return result
  }
  result
];
```

Other approach, which in long term is easier, is create a microservice that do this. One microservice could check the last events created and check is the keys already exist and then update the same event otherwise create a new event.

In both solutions we need to create a "customkey" with a "customvalue" in other to find out if the event already exist. This "customkey" can be created using the a unique key like currentime which is a number.

Hope this can help you.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the elaborate answer first:)
It is sadly not a solution to my problem. Hmm.. I will try to give an example that makes my problem more clear.. 
For example, I want to create an event that acts like an updateevent for many other events - Lets call this event UpdateEvent.
So in my SmartRule the "from" and "where" clause will take this UpdateEvent into account and not the events actually being updated. I already tried a join in my "from" clause but the smartrule did not trigger anymore.

Comment: If I could create the events which are to be updated with an ID when UpdateEvent is called for the first time, everything would work.

The Update is triggered when my UpdateEvent is called and in my UpdateEvent I have already all IDs from the Events updated. But creating an event with an ID seems not possible.

Comment: Not, create your custom id is not possible, but you can create your customkey with the value you want as I described in the answer. Then you just need to save the customsKey value and not the IDs of the events.